# How to enable Auto logon using MDT 2013 after Litetouch installation is over?

Tags: mdt

I have a Gold build image which i have used in my Task sequence 2 to create a device specific image by adding the drivers.The Gold build already has an autologon registry entry for the Administrator account which is what i want after Task sequence 2 is over but as MDT deletes any autologon entries in the registry the autologon towards the end doesnt seem to take place.

The things i have tried is **commented** the part in LiteCleanup.wsf which clears any Autologon entries from registry but that doesn't seem to work. 
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> The things i have tried is commented the part in LiteCleanup.wsf which clears any Autologon entries from registry but that doesn't seem to work.

Did you update the deployment share after this modification ?

---

Maybe you can add a command line task at the very end of the sequence and add the registry key with [this method](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/04/05/how-to-delete-and-add-registry-keys-from-the-command-line/).